# Pass username/password (Formdata) in a scrapy shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there a way to pass formdata in a scrapy shell? 
I am trying to scrape data from an authenticated session, and it would be nice to check xpaths and so on through a scrapy shell.

Comment: sry i am late, but do you still need a solution?

Answer (score 0):

one workaround is to first login using scrapy (using FormRequest) and then invoke inspect_response(response) in the parse method